# check the first element using css selector

Tags: jquery, css, selenium, css-selectors

I am trying to check if a particular element exists on a webpage using css. Using

```
$$("css=.class1 a")
```

returns

```
<a href="##################" id="ID-133333">Activate</a>
<a href="##################" id="ID-122222">Deactivate</a>
```

I need to check if Activate appears. Can some one please let me know how to get to Activate.

Page structure:

```
<div class = "class1">
  <div class = "class2">
    <a href="##################" id="ID-133333">Activate</a>
    <a href="##################" id="ID-122222">Deactivate</a>
```

Comment: *"using css ..."* - how exactly would that work ?

Comment: Do you want to check if `Activate` element displays/exist on the page with `selenium`?

Comment: @Saifur Yes. I need to check for Activate

Comment: @Maarten1909: `getElementsByClassName` (I believe that's what you're referring to) has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @alecxe Why doesn't $$("css=.class1 a.cointains('Activate')") work?

Comment: @DOSKrupp well, it should be contains, try: `div.class1 a:contains('Activate')`.

Comment: @alecxe Nope it didn't work.

Comment: @DOSKrupp hm, btw, what about the `first-of-type` approach I've suggested?

Comment: @alecxe It returns the whole child.  I need to check if Activate appears in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`first-of-type` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type):

```
css=.class1 a:first-of-type
```

Comment: I found other simple solution using @FindBy(linktext="Activate") does the job too

Comment: @DOSKrupp Sure, missed that! One my favorites :) Thank you for sharing and accepting the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can check if a class exist.

```js
$("#search").click(function() {
  if ($(".activate")[0]) {
    alert('Found activate');
  }
});

$("#search-2").click(function() {
  if (!$(".not-activate")[0]) {
    alert('Could not find not-activate');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" id="ID-133333" class="activate">Activate</a>

<a href="#" id="ID-122222" class="deactivate">Deactivate</a>

<br/>
<button id="search">Search activate class</button>
<button id="search-2">Search not-activate class</button>
```